# How to schedule USB drive to start only in specific days

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, backup

I have backup drive, and I have configured backup in Acronis every Friday. But to minimize chance of infecting "backup drive" with virus (for ex. cryptolocker) I want drive enabled only on FRIDAY. Is there some kind of script, which can disable USB Device and enable it again?

P.S. Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1):

> You can use batch which gives you a couple of options. You can edit
>   the registry key to disable usb devices from being used
>
> reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsbStor /v "Start" /t
>   REG_DWORD /d "4" /f
>
> To enable change value to 3.
>
> Or you can deny access to the files Usbstor.pnf and Usbstor.inf
>
> cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.pnf /d user cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.inf
>   /d user
>
> Where user is the user account that you want to deny access for.
>
> To enable use
>
> cacls %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.pnf /p user:R cacls
>   %windir%\Inf\Usbstor.inf /p user:R

Source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267236/how-disable-and-enable-usb-port-via-command-prompt

Or you can use Usbdeview or Microsoft Devcon.

Comment: Wouldn't this disable all USB devices?  And if you disabled it for the user account, what if a virus used a different account (quite common).  Also, viruses frequently make registry changes, there is no reason it could not change the registry entries back.

Comment: @tbenz9 - which one, I provided 3 options

Answer (score 1):

Simply offline the disk using a DISKPART script.  Bring it back online before your backups using a similar script (replace offline with online).

```
select disk 1
offline disk
```

Replace 1 with the disk number of your USB drive.  `list disk` will enable you to find this.

Comment: This is a great solution.  Create a small batch script with those commands and then just call the script using Windows Task Scheduler.  You'll need another script to turn the USB drive back online as well.  It should be fairly easy though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ! Looks working, but i must find tutorial how to make schedule with admin rights, i will answer, if i done it :D

Can somebody write me .BAT script which silently do these commands?

If i put it in BAT file, it will open only CMD then another window with DISKPART, and nothing happens

Thank you all for help !